# What are the configure options for Qt that enable dead keys usage?

Tags: qt, qt5

I use a bare Ubuntu LTS 16.04 vm to create an AppImage for one of my projects. I create a minimalistic static Qt for this, so that the AppImage's size is as small as possible. I recently managed to build a static Qt 5.14.2 with the following configure options:

```
../configure -prefix ~/Qt/5.14.2_static -opensource -confirm-license -release -static -optimize-size -no-opengl -no-gif -no-ico -no-libjpeg -skip qt3d -skip qtactiveqt -skip qtandroidextras -skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtcharts -skip qtconnectivity -skip qtdatavis3d -skip qtdeclarative -skip qtdoc -skip qtgamepad -skip qtgraphicaleffects -skip qtimageformats -skip qtlocation -skip qtmacextras -skip qtmultimedia -skip qtnetworkauth -skip qtpurchasing -skip qtquickcontrols -skip qtquickcontrols2 -skip qtremoteobjects -skip qtscript -skip qtscxml -skip qtsensors -skip qtserialbus -skip qtserialport -skip qtspeech -skip qtvirtualkeyboard -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebchannel -skip qtwebengine -skip qtwebglplugin -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtwebview -skip qtwinextras -skip qtxmlpatterns -nomake examples -nomake tests -nomake tools -qt-zlib -sql-sqlite -qt-sqlite -qt-libpng -qt-pcre -qt-xcb
```

Building my program and an AppImage works, I noticed however, that dead keys don't work. I use a German locale here, and pressing accent keys does nothing. E. g. when I input an `´` and an `e` into a `QLineEdit`, I simply get an `e` instead of `é`.

I first thought this was due to something missing in the vm, but when I do the same Qt build on my Gentoo host (where dead keys always have been working in Qt programs), I get the same result: the dead keys don't work. So most probably, this is due to wrong configuration.

I experimented with the `-libinput`, `-xkb`, `-xkbcommon` and `-qt-harfbuzz` configure switches, but I can't get dead keys to work.

Which configure options have to be set when building Qt so that dead keys work?

Edit: When I build Qt with this exact configure statement, but the shared version instead of the static one, the dead keys work. What does cause this?

Comment: you say: *when I do ´ + e, I simply get an e instead of é* . How to obtain the text or where we observe it? you must be more detailed.

Comment: It'a all over the program where one can type text. E. g. when typing something into a QLineEdit. I edited the text. As said, the odd thing is that if I build a shared Qt and link against it, everything works normally.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is a bug. I reported it on https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-83783 , including a minimal example producing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened due to a missing `QTPLUGIN` parameter. Imho this is almost impossible to figure out, but easy to solve:

Adding `QTPLUGIN += composeplatforminputcontextplugin` to the .pro file does the trick. `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QComposePlatformInputContextPlugin)` appears automatically in `project_plugin_import.cpp`.

Doing so, the dead keys work as expected with a static build.